# Is there a way to create a cmd shortcut for a specific folder on W7 or/and W8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-7, shortcuts

Let say i have 3 different folders that i want to access with CMD

- C:\Users\Henok\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp1\Debug>
- C:\Users\Henok\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp2\Debug>
- C:\Users\Henok\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp3\Debug>

I wonder if there is a way to create 3 different cmd shortcuts to access those directory (folders) individually without changing the default cmd directory location.

Forgive me for my broken English, and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a shortcut to `cmd.exe`
2. Set its Properties to change the `Start in` value.
3. When you click the shortcut, the program opens there.

[image: shortcut properties]

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to use a directory that way without changing directory (cd).

Maybe if you explain in details what you're trying to accomplish, we can find a workaround.

Comment: For example on windows 8 there is a way to start cmd windows from a specific folder by SHIFT + RIGHT CLICK --> Open cmd here.  What i want to accomplish is to make a short cut on desktop rather than finding a folder and doing SHIFT + RIGHT CLICK every time i want.

Comment: Oh sorry Hinstein I think I misunderstood your issue. But I'm glad someone found a solution :)

Comment: no need to say sorry, and thanks for your reply :)